# How can I define a color in Color.kt with simple way when I use Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I can use Code A to define a color in Color.kt file which is generated by Android Studio wizard automatically, it's OK.

I hope to define a color based `MaterialTheme.colors`, but Code B return the following error.

*@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function*

At present, I have to use Code C, it's not very good, is there a better way?

**Code A**

```
val IconColor = Color(0xFF2E7D32)
```

**Code B**

```
val IconColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(alpha = 0.76f)
```

**Code C**

```
@Composable
fun IconColor(): Color {
    return MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(alpha = 0.76f)
}
```

Comment: Where are you using these colours? Not in comosables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting that because `MaterialTheme.colors` the getter of this field is using `@compsable` scope, So I have found 2 ways you can declare your variable in `Colors.kt` in the way you want.

> 1:
>
> ```
> val IconColor1: @Composable () -> Color = { MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(alpha = 0.76f) }
> ```

> 2:
>
> ```
> val IconColor2: Color @Composable get() = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(alpha = 0.76f)
> ```

---

And I hope this was helpful

Answer (score 1):

Studio has the source for the material colours. Just `Ctrl`+`Click` on the name of the class/color and you're there.